# Nested SQL not return any data

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to execute the following SQL statement which consists of few nested queries as well.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(ccb.col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS col,
    LISTAGG(ccb.covered, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS covered,
    s.line,
    s.text
FROM   user_source s
       JOIN dbmspcc_units ccu ON s.name = ccu.name AND s.type = ccu.type
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbmspcc_blocks ccb ON ccu.run_id = ccb.run_id AND ccu.object_id = ccb.object_id AND s.line = ccb.line
WHERE  s.name = (SELECT u.name FROM dbmspcc_units u WHERE run_id = (SELECT MAX(r.run_id) FROM dbmspcc_runs r WHERE run_comment = 'Example'))
AND    s.type = (SELECT u.type FROM dbmspcc_units u WHERE run_id = (SELECT MAX(r.run_id) FROM dbmspcc_runs r WHERE run_comment = 'Example'))
AND    ccu.run_id = (SELECT MAX(r.run_id) FROM dbmspcc_runs r WHERE run_comment = 'Example')
AND ccb.NOT_FEASIBLE = 0
GROUP BY s.line, s.text
ORDER BY 3;
```

This query not returning any data, in fact, it's not finishing the execution. (Something like got trap in a recursive call)

But the same query work after replacing the nested query with hardcoded data.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(ccb.col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS col,
    LISTAGG(ccb.covered, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS covered,
    s.line,
    s.text
FROM   user_source s
       JOIN dbmspcc_units ccu ON s.name = ccu.name AND s.type = ccu.type
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbmspcc_blocks ccb ON ccu.run_id = ccb.run_id AND ccu.object_id = ccb.object_id AND s.line = ccb.line
WHERE  s.name = 'THREE_TST'
AND    s.type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
AND    ccu.run_id = 41
AND ccb.NOT_FEASIBLE = 0
GROUP BY s.line, s.text
ORDER BY 3;
```

Also when I run the nested queries separately it gives the above-hardcoded values correctly. What is here I'm doing in the nested queries?

Comment: do you have index on run_id at the table dbmspcc_units  ? and whats the exec time of the query : SELECT MAX(r.run_id) FROM dbmspcc_runs r WHERE run_comment = 'Example' ?

Comment: @AliFidanli No, I don't have an index. But the runtime of nested queries is very tiny.

Comment: can you add the index and try ? also the query can be simplyfy  =  (s.name,s.type ,  ccu.run_id) = (SELECT u.name, u.type, u.run_id FROM dbmspcc_units u WHERE run_id = (SELECT MAX(r.run_id) FROM dbmspcc_runs r WHERE run_comment = 'Example'))

Comment: Your query with hard coded values **is not** the same. It is missing the predicate which requires predicate `run_comment = 'Example'` Since that is an AND predicate if it is missing you will have nothing selected.